# Sorting Data with Space Contrainsts

Tags: sorting

Now the problem is pretty simple. You have 1000 MB and you have to sort it. Now the problem is you only have 100 MB space to sort the data. (Lets say the 1000 MB is stored in the Disk and you have only 100 MB Ram to sort the data. - At at any time you can only have 100 MB data in the Ram.)

Now I came up with this solution:

1. Divide the data into 10 parts - 100 MB each and sort it using Quick Sort.
2. Then write all the chunks of data into the Hard Drive.
3. Now pick the first 10 MB from each chunk and then merge. Now you have 100 MB. Now keep this 100 MB separated.
4. Now do the same thing. Pick the next 10 MB from each chunk and merge.
5. Keep doing this and then concatenate the data.

Now the problem I'm facing is as we're separately merging 100 MB each time when we concatenate we will be making mistakes. (These 100 MB should also be merged together.)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have to design that algorithm from scratch, it's called *external sorting*, in particular you might want *merge sort*

Comment: I know merge sort but how would this work? Because in merge sort you would need space of 1000 MB to merge all the data back together. Plus I don't know what external sorting is?

Comment: Think of the subchunks as a kind of sorted stream. You have all `n` substreams open at the same time and pick the smallest element from any of the `n` substreams. The external merge sort is a little different than the internal merge sort. Don't get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*External merge sorting* differs from the internal version in the merge phase. In your question you are trying to directly apply the internal merge algorithm to an external merge.

Hence you end up with having to merge two chunks of size `n / 2`. As you correctly note, that won't work because you run out of memory.

Let's assume that you have enough memory to sort `1/k` th of all elements. This leaves you with `k` sorted lists. Instead of merging two lists, you merge all `k` at once:

1. Pick an output buffer size. A good value seems to be `n / 2`. This leaves `n / 2` memory for input buffering or `m = n / (2 x k)` per subchunk.
2. Read the first `m` element from each subchunk. All memory is now used and you have the lowest `m` elements from each subchunk in memory.
3. From each of the `k` input buffers, choose the lowest value. Append this value into the output buffer. Repeat until one of your input buffers runs out.
4. If one of your input buffers runs out, read the next `m` elements from the subchunk on disk. If there are no more elements, you are done with the subchunk.
5. If the output buffer is full, append it to the output file and reset its position to the start.
6. Rinse and repeat from (3) until all subchunks run out.

The output file now is sorted.

You can think of the input buffers as a set of streaming buffers on sorted buckets. Check the streams and pick the *best* (i.e. lowest) element from all of them and save that one to the output list. From the outside it is a stream merge with smart prefetch and output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat step 3 and 4. N-1 number of times.

Comment: I do get that but the thing is concatenating the data won't sort it. For example you have a data set 1,2,3,4,5 and another data set 3,4,5,6. Concatenating it would give 1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6. But the final solution is not sorted. Do you get my point or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I am not clear in what i meant by repeating steps 3 and 4. let me take your example. suppose these 2 sorted sets are there 1,2,3,4,5 and  2,3,4,5,6.
loop 1> 1,2,3,4,5  :::   2,3,4,5,6. //taking first 10mb of sorted lists
loop 2> 1223  :::: 3445 :::: 56